# convert currency symbol to XML decimal entity reference within PHP 5.3.10

Tags: php, xml, type-conversion, php-5.3, html-entities

Is there anyway, within PHP 5.3.10, to convert a currency symbol - for example `£` to it's XML decimal entity reference `&#163;`?

I could use a "map" for all my currencies, but I would have thought this was possible with htmlentities or something similar.

This is for use within an XML document.

Unfortunately, `htmlspecialchars` doesn't do what i'm looking for. See example below:

```
error_log('POUND SIGN');
error_log(htmlspecialchars('&pound;', ENT_QUOTES));

error_log('EURO SIGN');
error_log(htmlspecialchars('&#0128;', ENT_QUOTES));

error_log('DOLLAR SIGN');
error_log(htmlspecialchars('$', ENT_QUOTES));
```

generates:

```
[Thu Apr 26 14:06:56 2012] [error] [client 192.168.10.2] POUND SIGN
[Thu Apr 26 14:06:56 2012] [error] [client 192.168.10.2] &amp;pound;
[Thu Apr 26 14:06:56 2012] [error] [client 192.168.10.2] EURO SIGN
[Thu Apr 26 14:06:56 2012] [error] [client 192.168.10.2] &amp;#0128;
[Thu Apr 26 14:06:56 2012] [error] [client 192.168.10.2] DOLLAR SIGN
[Thu Apr 26 14:06:56 2012] [error] [client 192.168.10.2] $
```

Comment: Maybe this reference can help you: http://inanimatt.com/php-convert-entities.html

Comment: @Jack Yes, that is quite helpful. The map used in the `convert_entity` function is something along the lines of what I am doing. I'm surprised there's nothing in PHP to handle this natively.

Comment: @Jack I have updated the inital question with the method I have written to alleviate this problem, but, as I say, i'm surprised this can't be done in PHP by use of a built-in function.

Comment: Yeah it's a pity, but it's pretty straightforward even in C code :) maybe I'll suggest this function to the PHP community and see how it rolls!

Comment: @Jack Yes, I think this would be something worthwhile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I have essentially done is this:

```
public function getCurrencyXMLDecimalEntity(string $symbol): string 
{
    $map = array(
            '&pound;'   => '&#163;',    // £ - Great British Pounds
            '&#0128;'   => '&#8364;',   // € - Euro
            '$'         => '&#36;'      // $ - US Dollars
    );

    return $map[$symbol];                
}
```

But this is just basic PHP and it can be done a number of ways, no doubt. Unfortunately though, it would seem, not with a built-in PHP function.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to convert symbols html entities, you can try using the [`htmlspecialchars()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) function.

Comment: Hmmm, I was aware of htmlspecialchars, but I don't believe it offers this functionality.

Comment: I Have updated the question with a result of what htmlspecialchars does. Unfortunately, it's not what i'm looking for.

Comment: Dude, try to watch this video. You will get the technique from this. I am sure or it. http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UuplJsiz3ag&feature=g-all-u

Comment: Thanks, but essentially what this is doing is a `str_replace` on a custom set of values that I want to "swap". You can see from my revised question that my `getCurrencyXMLDecimalEntity` is doing the same thing, just in a slightly more raw way.